# What is the maximum current of an electronic load?

Tags: resistance, current-measurement, circuit-theory, electronic-load

Here is the specification of an electronic load:

[image]

If the load is set in current mode, the current is limited to 25 A.

Nevertheless, if the current is set in resistor mode, I could think that it is only limited by the power (1500 W @ 20°C.)

Suppose we set the resistance to the minimum (10 mΩ.)  Does that mean that the current would be equal to 387 A?

$$I = \sqrt{\dfrac{P}{R}}$$

I think that it is not possible.

What is the maximum current? Is it a bit higher than 25 A or is it 25 A? I was thinking that it was possible to find an "SOA" of the electronic load into the datasheet, but I did not find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The voltage and currents on the load have to be constrained within **all** limits simultaneously: -

- Maximum current of 25 amps
- Maximum voltage of 750 volts
- Maximum product of voltage and current of 2400 watts (e.g. 10 amps and 240 volts)

> *I was thinking that it was possible to find an "SOA" of the electronic
> load into the datasheet, but I did not find it.*

You can make an SOA curve from the above three bullet points: -

[image]

Comment: ... and another diagonal for the maximum _continuous_ power going from 60V 25A to 750V 2A.

Comment: @mow yes you are quite correct.